# Row_Number over (partition by...) all columns

Tags: sql, row-number, partition-by

I have a view with something like 150 columns and I want to add an Id column to that view. Is it possible not to write all the column names in the over (partition by... ) statment?

something like this:

```
row_number over (partition by *) As ID?
```

Comment: No, this is not possible.  What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add a row number to the view, don't you just want an `order by` with no partition?

If so, you can use one of the following, depending on the database:

```
select row_number() over ()
select row_number() over (order by NULL)
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
```

Your approach would be enumerating identical rows, not providing a row number over all rows.